# Позиционирование модального окна внизу страницы

Tags: css, позиционирование, окно

В футере есть кнопка при нажатии на которую открывается модальное окно. Но открывается окно вверху страницы. Как спозиционировать так, чтобы наверх не улетало, а в футере открывалось?

```css
  .backdrop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: opacity .25s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  .modal {
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 400px;
    border: 3px solid var(--soclinks-bg-color);
    background-image: radial-gradient(#f3d4d9 35%, #fda9bd 55%);
    border-radius: 24px;
    transition: transform .25s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
  }
```

Comment: добавьте минимальный пример, ctrl+m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте использовать z-index.

т.е. backdrop будет z-index:0, а modal будет z-index: 1, к примеру.

вот тут неплохо все описано:http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index